# Not writing from the beginning in the spreadsheet. Excel VBA.

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to make an inventory system. I have available quantity and reorder quantity. The user clicks the alert button every now and then. If the reorder quantity is less than Available quantity an entry to this alert page is made. I am creating a fresh alert page every time the user clicks on "Alert" button. I am clearing the contents of this page everytime for that.

The problem I am facing is that MS excel is clearing the contents but not writing the new records from the second line (the first line has the column labels). If I have 5 contents in the warehouse before having current quantity < reorder quantity and the alert is generated in the alert page and then if I take care of those 5 (add quantities such that it is not less than reorder quantity anymore) and now I have 6th content that has its quantity less than reorder quantity, the other 5 are not displayed but the 6th is displayed in the 7th line and not the first line. Where am I getting it wrong. 
This happens even if I close the file and reopen it.

Thanks

```
row = 2
Worksheets("Alerts").UsedRange.ClearContents
Worksheets("Alerts").Range("B1") = Str(row)
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 1) = "Warehouse Name"
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 2) = "Name"
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 3) = "Quantity available"
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 4) = "Reorder Quantity"
rows_present_alerts = Worksheets("Alerts").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
While (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 1) <> "")
    If (CLng(Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 3)) <    
       CLng(Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 4))) Then
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(rows_present_alerts, 1) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 1))
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(rows_present_alerts, 2) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 2))
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(rows_present_alerts, 3) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 3))
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(rows_present_alerts, 4) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 4))
       rows_present_alerts = rows_present_alerts + 1
    End If
   row = row + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use row in your loop rather than row_present_alerts if you know that you are going to start on the second row each time?  It doesn't make a lot of sense to me that you are clearing out the sheet, and then worried about the number of rows in the used range.  Not to mention, UsedRange is notoriously unpredictable, especially if you have formatting or the like on the sheet.

I think this is what you are after:

```
row = 2
loopCounter = 2

Worksheets("Alerts").Cells.ClearContents
Worksheets("Alerts").Range("B1") = Str(row)
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 1) = "Warehouse Name"
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 2) = "Name"
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 3) = "Quantity available"
Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(1, 4) = "Reorder Quantity"

While (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(loopCounter, 1) <> "")
    If (CLng(Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 3)) <    
       CLng(Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(row, 4))) Then
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(row, 1) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(loopCounter, 1))
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(row, 2) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(loopCounter, 2))
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(row, 3) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(loopCounter, 3))
       Worksheets("Alerts").Cells(row, 4) = (Worksheets("InventoryID").Cells(loopCounter, 4))
       row = row + 1
    End If
    loopCounter = loopCounter + 1
Wend
```

Comment: well I used two variables cuz the sheet InventoryID will have lots of rows and not all will qualify for "Alerts" (The condition is that the reorder quantity should be less than available quantity). So if 2nd 8th and 10th item in InventoryID needs reorder, my alert sheet will have records in 2nd, 8th and 10th row and rest will be empty..

Comment: @Ankur, yes two variables is the proper way to handle this, and I kept that approach in my solution.  I just removed the bit about the used range and cleared the whole sheet.  I think this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any formatting saved in the cells in your Alerts sheet? Excel has a number of oddities in the way it calculates and works with the UsedRange, and ClearContents only clears data, not formatting etc.

Is there any reason you could not just delete the Alerts worksheet and then create a new one each time? That should solve the problem.

Comment: You mean something like this ................. Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Sheets("Alerts").Delete
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Worksheets.Add.Name = "Alerts"

Comment: Thanks Vicky!! it works in this case, but there's another similar situation I'm facing in which I cannot delete the worksheet. What should I do in case I don't wanna delete the worksheet !!